# convert Javascript object to dom element

Tags: javascript, dom

I've had this confusion since long.
There is an error called cannot read property of null on chrome inspector.

Upon searching and reading, i found that a property (eg style) can be applied to a DOM element, but if it is rendered as a javascript object it gives the above error.

So how do i go about this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #test {background:black;width:30px;height:30px;}
        </style>
        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById('test');
            a.style.background = "#f00";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="test">
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i did alert(typeof a); it gives as object. So how do I, in general, change properties of elements ??

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking... in your example, `a` does contain a DOM element, and the way you are referencing the properties is correct and should work if the element is in the DOM when the script runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `#test` doesn't exist when the script is executed. The script is executed immediately as the page is loaded, and at the point when the browser executes the script, it hasn't gotten to `<div id="text"></div>`, so `document.getElementById('test')` returns `null`.

`null` values don't have properties, so calling: `a.style.background...` causes JavaScript to error out. If you'd attached this script to `body.onload`, the callback function provided would execute *after* the rest of the page was loaded:

```
document.body.onload = function(){
  var a = document.getElementById('test');
  if ( a ) //just a check to make sure that `a` was set so that it doesn't error again.
  {
    a.style.background = "#f00";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript is running before the page has finished loading.

You need to put your javascript inside an window.onload like this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('test');
  a.style.background = "#f00";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the DOM to be completely loaded before calling that script, because when you are calling the code the element isn't created yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5Qqs/1/